# Create a card deck data structure in c++ using arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement

I am attempting to create an array of size 52 that contains all of the cards in a standard deck of playing cards. How would I do this without manually initializing each of the cards?

Here is my code:

```cpp
    int main()
    {
        int suit;
        int face;
        int deck[52] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52 };

        char suit[4] = { 'D','H','C','S' };

        int face[13] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10 };

        for (int count = 0; count < 52; count++) {
            face = deck[count] % 13;
            suit = deck[count] / 13;
        }



        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `deck` is just an array of `int`s. Perhaps you should make a small `Card` struct, so that the face, suit and value can be store in one place.

Comment: Needs clarity. Unable to understand what you want to do here.

Comment: A deck of cards has 52 cards I'm trying to store each unique card on deck[52]

Comment: Tip: Cards are often represented as `2C`, `3S`, with `T` for "ten" and `K`, `Q`, `J`, etc. so two letters can represent one unique card. This helps with debugging.

Comment: This is a good usage of enums. You can have an enum type for the different card faces ex. `enum faces = {ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING};`

Comment: What's the reason of hardcoding an array of 52 consecutive integers?

Comment: @Ender_The_Xenocide Less useful when you want to use that in a look-up table.

Comment: I'm still on my second semester. That's why I'm trying to make this as readable as possible.

Comment: Do you need them to be shuffled or in order?

Comment: First I need them in order and later on, I'll shuffle em with a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, I would first create two enumerated types for the faces and suites like so:

```cpp
enum faces = {ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING};
enum suite = {DIAMONDS, SPADES, CLUBS, HEARTS};
```

Then, I would create a card struct to wrap these two types together.

```cpp
struct Card {
   suite s;
   face f;
};
```

And finally, I would create a class with a complete deck containing a constructor that iterates through the faces and suite types and creates all the different combinations. It would also include basic member functions and variables to access the deck. I would also probably implement the deck as a vector.

Here's how the constructor would work:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   for(int j = 0;j < 13; j++) {
      Card temp;
      temp.s = i;
      temp.f = j;
   }
}
```

**EDIT:** And if you are going to shuffle them, you can just easily add a member function to do so.

Comment: Can you explain enum with more detail? We haven't been taught enums yet.

Comment: Enums just let you create your own class

Comment: This should be `enum class`. It's much safer.

Comment: cigien's answer seems way simpler. Which one should I follow?

Comment: Depends on your style, my solution is more complex, but cleaner. Also, if you are worried about types being used outside of the class, you can make the enums and structs private members of the deck class.

Comment: When storing unique data types, I always go for classes, but that's just me.

Comment: Would be cleaner if you used a sentinel value at the end of each enum so you don't have to use the literals 4 and 13 in your for loop.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fairly simple way to do it using just `int`s to represent the suit, and value. The important thing, I think, is to store *both* the face and value together, so that you don't have 2 different containers to keep track of.

```
struct Card
{
  int suit, value;  
};
```

Now you can fill up an array of cards quite easily:

```
Card cards[52];
for (int i = 0; i < 52; ++i)
{
  cards[i].suit = i % 4; // 4 suits
  cards[i].value = i % 13; // 13 values
}
```